# How to do the Raspberry Pi emulation with QEMU on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: noobs, qemu

I'm trying to emulate the NOOBS image with QEMU on Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried [this](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/) link, to perform the emulation. But on execution of this step,

qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 512 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda recovery.img

****audio: Could not init `oss' audio driver
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.****

I'm getting the executed terminal window.

Help me in setting up the emulation with qemu for NOOBS image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qemu does not support 512 mb of CPU. Try this command with option of sound hardware:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 512 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda recovery.img -soundhw ac97
```

Comment: On executing the command,                       audio: Could not init `oss' audio driver
Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

Comment: @Madhumitha did you get it working?

Comment: @Coombesy No. I just dropped an idea  for working on it for sometime